# Can't remove space right for element

Tags: html, css, mobile

On my laptop I can remove the space right for the element by making it bigger and then set `overflow: hidden` but on my iPhone it will just make a horizontal scroll bar. How can I fix this? I have tried to use media queries but it doesn't work either.
[image: Example]

Comment: It would be better if you post the sample code causing problem. Laptop and mobile are different things.

Comment: I only use the overflow and width properties

Comment: With overflow hidden and width property... You can control the scroll...

Comment: It doesn't work on my mobile..

Comment: There could be something wrong in your code...

Comment: It is not only on my mobile, I have tried 5 deferent mobiles

Comment: I guess you should help yourself...

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean try different css property and debug so that you could get solution to your problem

Comment: I did that before I asked here, that's why I asked

Comment: You may want to look into media queries to control the look of the site in a different way for mobile devices -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Object is missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by using the `overflow: hidden` attribute on `<HTML>` like this `<HTML style="overflow: hidden">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code-

```
elementSelector{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: I have that code, it works on my laptop and my desktop but not on mobile

Comment: You should paste your sample code causing the problem

Comment: try  `overflow-x:hidden !important;`

Comment: Create a JS Fiddle then... As problem specific to iPhone or OS can be identified only by seeing structure or CSS you have used.

Comment: I will do it later, I'm on mobile